# What does $\sin(a,b)$ mean in the absorber theory of radiation?

Tags: electromagnetism, notation

I'm doing a revision of the [absorber theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wheeler%E2%80%93Feynman_absorber_theory) of radiation by Wheeler and Feynman (that you can see here: "[Interaction with the Absorber as the Mechanism of Radiation](http://ayuba.fr/mach_effect/absorber_wheeler_feynman_.pdf)" - page 161) and I have encountered the expression $-(e a/r_k c^2) \sin(a,r_k)$, where $a$ is the acceleration of the source and $r_k$ is the position for a particle of the absorber, which gives us the retarded field for a non-relativistic source.

Does anyone understand what the notation $\sin(a,r_k)$ stands for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It stands for sine of the angle between the two vectors in the braces, in this case, between the retarded radius vector $r_k$ and the charged particle acceleration $\mathscr{U}$.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I thought it could be that but I wasn't sure